# How to read JSON text from Sql Server 2016 table column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

I have following JSon data in Sql Server.

```
{
 "PartnerName": null,
 "PartnerCurrencyCode": "UAD",
 "PricingConditions": [
  {
    "PricingConditionId": 659853,
    "ConditionTypeCode": "ABCD",
    "ConcessionItemTypeCode": "ABC",
    "PriceLevel": null
  }
],
"CurrencyMultiplier": 0
}
```

Expected Results is:

```
PartnerName  PartnerCode    PartnerCurrencyCode  PricingConditionId
NULL         NULL           UAD                   659853
```

I have read that Sql Server 2016 has the Capabilities of reading JSON Data and Tried with the following Queries.

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$')
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
WITH (PartnerName NVARCHAR(50) '$.PartnerName',
     PartnerCode nvarchar(50) '$.PartnerCode',
     PartnerCurrencyCode nvarchar(50) '$.PartnerCurrencyCode',
     PricingConditionId nvarchar(50)   '$.PricingConditions.PricingConditionId')
```

Query 2 Results:

```
PartnerName  PartnerCode    PartnerCurrencyCode  PricingConditionId
NULL         NULL           UAD                  NULL
```

I Was Expecting "PricingConditionId" Value is - 659853

Comment: What output does the second query give you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated the Question with second Query results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT PartnerName,
       PartnerCode,
       PartnerCurrencyCode,
       [PricingConditions[0]].PricingConditionId AS ProductID1
FROM OPENJSON (@json) 
WITH (
    PartnerName NVARCHAR(50),
    PartnerCode NVARCHAR(50),
    PartnerCurrencyCode NVARCHAR(50),
    [PricingConditions[0]].PricingConditionId NVARCHAR(50)
) AS Partners
```

Here is a [link to a great article](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/11/01/reading-json-string-with-nested-elements-sql-server-2016-part-3/) which discusses several approaches to handle your problem.